# Javascript SQL Insert Loop

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, loops, cordova

I'm attempting to pass a function an array that should run through a loop and call a db.transaction for each incremented SQL statement.

```
function updateColorData (colorArray) {
    for (var i=0; i<colorArray.length; i++) {
        var sql = 'INSERT INTO SPColorData (color) VALUES (\''+colorArray[i]+'\')';
        if (i < colorArray.length-1) {
            db.transaction(function (tx) {tx.executeSql(sql, [], gameOptionSuccess, errorCB)}, errorCB);
        } else {
            db.transaction(function (tx) {tx.executeSql(sql, [], colorDataQuery, errorCB)}, errorCB);
        }
    }
}
```

As a test I'm calling the updateColorData function passing in an array like this

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

but when I have the database read back the information it received I'm getting

```
['four', 'four', 'four', 'four']
```

I realize that calling 4 database transactions in a loop like this is not the most efficient method but I'm not sure why this isn't working or what other method to try.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain which library you're using to execute queries from client side?

Comment: I'm developing for iOS using SQLite with Cordova framework. Is that the information you needed?

Comment: [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/402037) + [Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/) (also known as: [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection))

Comment: Thanks. However could you explain what `colorDataQuery` and `gameOptionSuccess` do? They are callBack functions.

Comment: gameOptionSuccess is empty right now but colorDataQuery just calls a Select query that re-renders out the javascript array I have that stores the data from the database.

Comment: Could you also add your test example (the one calling `updateColorData`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new scope for `i` before you call the database function; try this:

```
function updateColorData (colorArray) {
    for (var i=0; i<colorArray.length; i++) {
        (function(i){
            var sql = 'INSERT INTO SPColorData (color) VALUES   (\''+colorArray[i]+'\')';
            if (i < colorArray.length-1) {
                db.transaction(function (tx) {tx.executeSql(sql, [], gameOptionSuccess, errorCB)}, errorCB);
            } else {
            db.transaction(function (tx) {tx.executeSql(sql, [], colorDataQuery, errorCB)}, errorCB);
            }
        })(i);
    }
}
```

That creates an individual function scope for each value of `i`, using an anonymous function. You need to do this because the `for` loop in your original example keeps updating `i` without waiting for your database function to return. So you need to create "safe" contexts for your database functions to run without the `for` loop changing the value of `i`, and that's exactly what the anonymous functions provide.

Comment: Could you please explain to why this works and the posted example won't?

Comment: Tried to explain in more depth.